# State not captured by callback in React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this component that uses `useState`, and wraps its children in a `Modal` component, which is an old component from our application, and the modal component happens to be a total nightmare. But it takes an `acceptData` object which has a `callback` prop for when the "accept" button is clicked.

My issue is that my component is getting its state updated via another child (see `onFileReadComplete`), but then later when the button is clicked, that state is null. I can even see in the React dev tools that the state is *not* null, it has the value I expect.

Here is the component:

```js
const CSVEditSwitcher = ({ acceptData, hideData }) => {
  const [parsedData, setParsedData] = useState(null);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const enterLineups = lineupObject => dispatch(csvEditAPI(lineupObject));

  const modalProps = {
    className: "csv-upload",
    commonHide: true,
    acceptData: {
      actionName: "Submit",
      className: acceptData.className,
      callback: () => {
        if (!parsedData) {
          console.log("no data!"); // we keep getting here!
          return;
        }
        enterLineups(parsedData.masterLineups).then(acceptData.callback);
      },
    },
    hideData,
    validator: () => true,
  };

  return (
    <Modal {...modalProps}>
      {!parsedData ? (
        <UploadEditTemplate
          onFileReadComplete={data => {
            console.log({ data }); // this is always correct!
            setParsedData(data);
          }}
        />
      ) : (
        <ImportResults {...parsedData} />
      )}
    </Modal>
  );
};
```

In case it's some crazy `this` issue, I've tried replacing the callback with a `function () { }` syntax, to no avail.

There's nothing interesting in the call point for the callback in `Modal`:

```js
  accept(e) {
    if (!e) return;
    if (e.key && (e.key !== "Enter" || e.key !== "Return")) return;

    const { acceptCallback } = this.state;
    console.log(acceptCallback, e);
    if (acceptCallback) acceptCallback(e);
  }
```

### Update

As a hail-mary, I tried converting this to a class component (wrapping it in a functional component that provides the hook values). It actually works, but **only** when accessing `this.state.parsedData` explicitly in the callback. i.e., I have `const { parsedData } = this.state` at the top of the `render` method for the other uses of that value, but the destructured variable *does not work* in the callback.

I would love if anyone could lend insight on what the hell is going on here!

Comment: I think you need to take the code out of the callback and stuff it into a useEffect hook with parsedData in the dependency array. That way, when setParsedData happens, the effect will trigger and then run the enterLineups promise.

Comment: But I want the effect to happen when the button is clicked, not when the data is set.

Answer (score 0):

While destructuring props in injection (`{...modalProps}`...), you create a new instance in memory. Therefore `callback` prop will always have initial `parsedData` value.

My suggestion is to use `callback` as a reference to `useCallback` which aware to state manipulation

```
 const callback = useCallback(() => {
        if (!parsedData) {
          console.log("no data!")
          return;
        }
        enterLineups(parsedData.masterLineups).then(acceptData.callback);
      }, [parsedData])

 const modalProps = {
    className: "csv-upload",
    commonHide: true,
    acceptData: {
      actionName: "Submit",
      className: acceptData.className,
      callback
    },
    hideData,
    validator: () => true,
  };
```

Comment: Wow, that’s brilliant! Amazing catch, I’ll give it a try.